# Where should I install bootloader on a triple boot system? (Windows, macOS and Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bootloader, macosx

I'm dualbooting Windows 10 and macOS Monterey (Hackintosh).

I'm going to install Ubuntu and triple boot but
I don't where should I install my bootloader.
I'll boot from OpenCore's own boot manager.

Comment: I installed Windows and macOS with Hackintosh, unfortunately I don't have a Mac.

Comment: It has been a log time since I've done this.  Make sure linux is booting in EFI mode and not legacy and it should automatically install the bootloader.

Comment: I'm in EFI mode but I need to select bootloader location manually. ("/dev/sda", "/dev/sda1" etc.)

Comment: If it wants you to select a partition, you are not in efi mode. rEFInd can help you boot linux on the mac in EFI mode.  Converting an already installed linux from legacy to efi mode is not hard, I might add an answer later if someone else doesn't do it first.

Comment: I flashed the ISO with GPT mode in Rufus. Is that enough?

Comment: The thing I say is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj1wt.png

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy is then how it installs. And Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot on drive you install into, Ubuntu does not, but really should. Change drive to gpt, with gparted, if old MBR. With UEFI you get an ESP- efi system partition, if one does not exist, but Ubuntu versions 22.04 & before will only install grub boot files in an ESP on first drive. First drive as defined by UEFI, not by mounts after wards. NVMe drives are typically before sdX drives and lowest motherboard port of sdX drives, if same speeds is usually first drive.

Comment: I really didn't understand what've you said. I have 1 disk only and I'm trying to install Ubuntu as a third OS. There is a thing called "Device for boot loader installation". What should I choose in that moment? /dev/sda or EFI partition? It's simple.

Comment: What release are you trying to install?  There are different intallers used, and as oldfred mentioned, the one for Ubuntu 22.04 simply ignores your input for bootloader location. 23.04, use sda, the default and the one EFI partition will be found and used.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.